# Porque apareço como "modificador" se não fiz nada importante?

Tags: bug, suporte, status-intencional, pergunta-específica

O que fiz:

- dei o 4º voto para reabrir;
- reverti meu voto negativo;
- removi um comentário obsoleto.

Mas [não modifiquei nada na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/16247/timeline), porque aparece meu nome?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PS:** o [5º voto pra reabrir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/16247/revisions) foi meu, apareciam 3 votos e o 4º e 5º devem ter sido feitos quase ao mesmo tempo. De todos modos, não concordo com "modificado por..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O ato de reabrir a pergunta precisa fazer com que ela apareça no topo da página inicial, afinal ela foi modificada. Para tal essa modificação precisa de um tempo e de um usuário. Mesmo sendo 5 os que reabriram, o sistema pode mostrar apenas um na home. Aparentemente o último vira o "culpado". Diria que isso é [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: É, faz sentido total.

Comment: Isso mostra também a responsabilidade extra que recai sobre quem dá o último voto para fechar ou reabrir. Eu sempre reflito um pouco mais antes de votar quando a pergunta está "pendurada" por apenas um voto.